# Calcular Valores de Parcelas Diferentes

Tags: php

Galera, tenho uma planilha em Excel com várias linhas com valores de Produtos.

Irei importar esses valores para o MySQL.

Por exemplo:

**PRODUTO        VALOR**
PRODUTO X      R$ 700,00

Preciso dividir esses R$ 700,00 em X parcelas, porém essas parcelas não podem ter valores iguais ... Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Podes dar algum exemplo com numeros? queres fazer isso no excel ou com php?

Comment: nao entendi essa linha "Por exemplo: PRODUTO VALOR PRODUTO X 700,00"

Comment: @Sergio
Por exemplo, tenho um produto de R$ 1900,00 e gostaria de dividir em 5 Parcelas.

Estou fazendo em PHP

Comment: @AndreiCoelho Acabei de arrumar, não tinha pulado a linha.

Comment: Tem alguma regra a seguir? Por exemplo, um produto de R$ 100,00 em 3x poderia ser 1 de 10,00, outra de 0,01 e outra de 89,99?

Comment: @BrunoRigolon, sem Regras chará, seriam valores aleatórios mesmo.

Por exemplo, no caso do Produto de R$ 1900,00, uma parcela pode ser de 100 reais e as demais maiores.

Comment: Pode descrever qual é a relação entre Excel e PHP? Aliás, muitas informações triviais já foram dadas nos comentários. Busque [edit] a pergunta e deixá-la mais clara com todos esses detalhes.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, Me desculpe!
Me expressei mal na pergunta. Irei editar

Answer (score 1):

[**Exemplo - Ideone**](https://ideone.com/WB4nxU)

```
$parcelas=11;

$segredo = (1 + $parcelas) * ($parcelas / 2);

$valor="R$ 1900,30";

    //replace para retirar R$ e trim para retirar espaço
    $preco=trim(str_replace("R$","",$valor));
    
    //armazenando virgula centavos
    $decimal= substr($preco,(strlen($preco)-3),strlen($preco));
    
    //retirando virgula centavos 
    $preco=(str_replace($decimal,"",$preco));
    
    //calculando valores das parcelas
    for ($x = 1; $x <= ($parcelas-1); $x++) {
       $parcela = intval((($preco*$x)/$segredo));
       echo ("R$ ". number_format($parcela, 2, ',', '.'))."<br>";
       $somatorio=$somatorio+$parcela;
    }
    
    //calculo da ultima parcela
    $ultima=$preco-$somatorio;
    echo ("R$ ".($ultima.$decimal));
```

Quer saber o que é a variável  `$segredo`? clique na interjeição.

> A variável `$segredo` é o somatório dos números de 1 até a quantidade de parcelas. Generalizando, soma dos n primeiros números naturais.

DOCUMENTAÇÃO

- [trim](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.trim.php)
- [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php)
- [substr](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php)
- [strlen](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strlen.php)
- [intval](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.intval.php)
- [number_format](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.number-format.php)

Comment: Gostei da sua resposta @LeoCaracciolo. Mas e se for 12 parcelas? Ou 11?

Comment: @Andrei Coelho, se gostou paga :) Editei a pergunta para qualquer quantidade de parcelas.

Comment: Rsrs... Agora sim. =)